# Inheritance in Ruby / Sinatra

Tags: ruby, inheritance, sinatra

I'm working on a ruby project using Sinatra as a framework and have a question about extending classes.

Lets say I have a User class which is extended by an Admin, does the Admin have to be defined in User.rb? I've tried putting it in Admin.rb but I get an error saying:

```
admin.rb:1: uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

Thanks.

Comment: what about require 'user.rb'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the Admin class, you have to require the file that contains the definition of User so that ruby knows what User is when it sees the Admin class definition.

```
require 'user.rb'

class Admin < User

   ...
   ...

end
```